# -[NSPrintInfo setScalingFactor:] equivalent pre-Snow Leopard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-leopard

`NSPrintInfo` has the following method to change the scale of the printed document. However it is only available starting in OSX 10.6

```
- (void)setScalingFactor:(CGFloat)scalingFactor
```

How can I scale my print on Leopard 10.5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a potentially useful web page](http://chanson.livejournal.com/48448.html) (which also has some useful looking source code -- including scaling -- in the comments).  Why not use it for your 10.5 case and use the proper `NSPrintInfo` stuff for the 10.6 & newer case?